# Socket communication between C and python code

Tags: python, c, string, sockets

I have a python socket server that sends strings to a C program (client) that prints the string, then sends it back to the python program that prints it too. The communication works, but if it sends a long string, then a short one, the current and previous data kinda merges. Here's the example:

Output:

```
5.0standing0.0                //That is how it should look like
5.0walk0ing0.055111512313e-17 //After the long string
```

python code (just gets called in a loop):

```
import socket
import sys

# Create a TCP/IP socket
sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)

# Bind the socket to the port
server_address = ('localhost', 8888)
print >>sys.stderr, '\nstarting up on %s port %s\n' % server_address
sock.bind(server_address)

# Listen for incoming connection
sock.listen(1)

def send_control(state,xdiff,xactual):
  connection, client_address = sock.accept()
  connection.sendall(str(xactual)+str(state)+str(xdiff))
  data = connection.recv(2000)
  print data
  data = '\0'
```

C code (gets called in a loop too):

```
void comm_func() 
{
  int sock;
  int i=0;
  struct sockaddr_in server;
  char message[1024] , server_reply[2000];

  //Create socket
  sock = socket(AF_INET , SOCK_STREAM , 0);
  if (sock == -1)
  {
      printf("Could not create socket");
  }
  // puts("Socket created");

  server.sin_addr.s_addr = inet_addr("127.0.0.1");
  server.sin_family = AF_INET;
  server.sin_port = htons( 8888 );

  //Connect to remote server
  if (connect(sock , (struct sockaddr *)&server , sizeof(server)) < 0)
  {
      perror("connect failed. Error");
  }

  // Receive a reply from the server
  if( recv(sock , server_reply , 2000 , 0) < 0)
  {
      puts("recv failed");
  }
  puts(server_reply);
  write(sock,server_reply,50);
  for (i=0; i< strlen(server_reply); i++)
  {
    server_reply[i] = '\0';
  }
  close(sock);
}
```

Can anybody help me?

Comment: The received string is not null terminated, so [UB](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior). Easy fix `char server_reply[2000] = {0}`

Comment: Do not never expect `recv()` to return as much as it was told to. Check it's return value, ever. Also test it for `0`. As well take into account that TCP is stream oriented. N sends might trigger M receives, with N>M or N<M or even sometimes with N=M.

Comment: Voting to close this as an implicit call for documentation, which does not seem to be around.

Comment: The easiest way to do this is to not use raw sockets, but to use a fast and safe message library like ZeroMQ.

Comment: @Taywee Learning experience, I imagine. I can't imagine anyone actually needing the scenario in the question for anything *real*

Comment: `print >> sys.stderr` Please don't use Python 2; Python 3 is much better and should always be preferred

Answer (score 1):

Change

```
  // Receive a reply from the server
  if( recv(sock , server_reply , 2000 , 0) < 0)
  {
      puts("recv failed");
  }
```

Into:

```
  ssize_t len;
  // Receive a reply from the server
  if( (len = recv(sock , server_reply , 2000 , 0)) < 0)
  {
      puts("recv failed");
      close(sock);
      return -1;
  }
  server_reply[len] = 0;
```

As both @LP and @ack mention in the comments, the issue is that the short message isn't NUL terminated, which is normal for socket communication where 0 is a valid byte to send.